# Execute complete function only once in jQuery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate the font size of some text:

```
$("p").delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000, function() {
    alert("Done");
})​;
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/e6FFt/)

I want to do something after animating the `<p>`s, which in the example is `alert`, but it surprisingly runs it for each `<p>`, and that's not what I want. Is there a possible way to make it just run once or is it not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $p = $("p");
var lastIndex = $p.length - 1;

$p.delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000, function() {
    if ($p.index($(this)) == lastIndex) {
        alert("Done");
    }
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6FFt/2)

Comment: I like this index method that I don't have to create extra variables. Thanks!

Comment: @Derek: It *does* create two extra variables, by the way: `lastIndex` and `$p`...

Comment: @minitech, I put those 2 directly inside the `function()`, that's why.

Answer (score 10):

Just to notice, you can also use a [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/promise/):

> Return a Promise object to observe when all actions of a certain type
>   bound to the collection, queued or not, have finished.

**First example ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ2sv/)):**

```
$("p").delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000).promise().done(function(){
    alert("done");
});​
```

**Second example ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ2sv/1/)):**

```
$.when($("p").delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000)).done(function(){
    alert("done");
});​
```

Comment: Actually, this is much nicer. +1

Comment: The result is the same. These 2 methods (promise and when) return a promise object, used to attach callback like done().

Answer (score 2):

You could just keep a flag, since they should animate simultaneously:

```
var done = false;

$("p").delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000, function() {
    if(!done) {
        done = true;
        alert("Done");
    }
})​;
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/e6FFt/1/)

Comment: This will work well enough in most cases, and is much cleaner, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Give the P-tag in question an ID and select that ID rather than every P tag on the page. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/LR8uP/1/

Or if you want to animate every P-tag but run the function only once, add a state variable, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/LR8uP/2/

Comment: No, I want to animate all `<p>`s but only executes once.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be used as a generic 'countdown' type of function.

```
// Function that returns a function,
// which when invoked 'count' number of times,
// will invoke the function 'fn'
function runOnZero (count, fn) {
    return function () {
        if (--count <= 0) {
            fn();
        }
    };
}

// Get all the <p>s
var ps = $("p");

// Do your thing after ps.length calls
var whenAllDone = runOnZero(ps.length, function () {
   alert("Done");
});

ps.delay(500).animate({
    "font-size": "+=50"
}, 1000, whenAllDone)​;
```

Comment: The `whenAllDone` function is called once for each `<p>` in the list (after each `<p>` has been animated). When `whenAllDone` is called, it decrements a counter. When the counter reaches zero, the *real* function is called. The real function is the one that calls `alert()`. So although `whenAllDone` will be called `ps.length` times, it will only call `alert()` once, for the last `<p>`.