# Removing elements and then adding them again

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I've got this document tree sub-tree:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to empty the `childNodes` of `#content`, and then populate it again with `<div>`s having the `class="tile"`.
Here is what I've done.

```
$(".tile").fadeOut( showTileSpeed, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});


tiles[tileIndex]();// function adding .tiles to my #content

$(".tile").first().fadeIn(showTileSpeed, function showNext() {
    $(this).next(".tile").fadeIn(showTileSpeed, showNext);
});
```

It seems that the .tiles are added before the `remove()` is called so that nothing happens on screen...

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior? It appears that adding a timer is not a good solution.

Thanks!

Comment: `tile` you're right. Question edited.

Comment: Is it possible give us a demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).remove();` is called `showTileSpeed`  milliseconds after `fadeOut` was called. But `tiles[tileIndex]()` is called immediately after `fadeOut` was called.

You should add the tiles again once all the tiles have been removed. You can achieve this by passing the selected elements to [`$.when` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and register a callback (with [`.done()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)) on the returned promised object. The callback gets called once all animations have been completed:

```
var $tiles = $(".tile").fadeOut(showTileSpeed, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});

$.when($tiles).done(function() {      // <-- after all animations do this
    tiles[tileIndex]();

    $(".tile").first().fadeIn(showTileSpeed, function showNext() {
        $(this).next(".tile").fadeIn(showTileSpeed, showNext);
    });
});
```

See also [Execute complete function only once in jQuery animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354036/execute-complete-function-only-once-in-jquery-animation) (especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354286/218196)).

---

**Update:** Since it seems that calling `.remove()` interferes with the tests for the animation state, moving the call to `.remove()` might be a better solution:

```
var $tiles = $(".tile").fadeOut(showTileSpeed);

$.when($tiles).done(function() {
    $tiles.remove();
    tiles[tileIndex]();

    $(".tile").first().fadeIn(showTileSpeed, function showNext() {
        $(this).next(".tile").fadeIn(showTileSpeed, showNext);
    });
});
```

But if you only want to update the content of the elements, you don't have to remove them from the DOM.

Comment: Never heard about these functions. I'll give it a try and let you know but it seems very promising, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work only if I choose between `fadeOut()` or `remove()`. While playing your code in my environement, I have to click twice on my button to make it work.

Since the fading effect is just for enhancement, I'll go without it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Mmmh. Maybe the problem is `.remove`. It also removes jQuery data from the elements and maybe this is needed to determine the state of the animation. Try `$(this).detach()` or remove the `fadeOut` callback and put `$tiles.remove()` inside the callback passed to `.done`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean? Anyway, take look at this, is this what you need?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tile").fadeOut( showTileSpeed, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        tiles[tileIndex]();// function adding .tiles to my #content
        $(".tile").first().fadeIn(showTileSpeed, function showNext() {
            $(this).next(".tile").fadeIn(showTileSpeed, showNext);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The code in the callback is executed for each `.tile` element. I don't think, e.g. `tiles[tileIndex]()` should be executed (in this case) three times, only once.

Comment: @FelixKling: you're right and furthermore, I've already tried this solution but the `tiles[]()` function seemed to be running before the `remove()`